# Clear All text icon not working in iOS/iPad when keypad open

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a search textbox which has a clear all icon which cleares the text out.

Note: I am not using the HTML5 default clear all icon & instead have a custom clear all icon.

It's working fine on most browsers as well as Android phones.

But on an iPad/iphone, if the keypad is open then it doesn't clears the text when the icon is clicked. If the keypad is closed then it does clear the text.

Don't know why. If someone can help.

Here's the code: Also here's a working jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8m9oeymx/

HTML:

```
<input class="clearable" type="search" id="searchTerm" value="" placeholder="Start typing fund name" />
```

CSS:

```
input[type="search"] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
}

input[type="search"]::-ms-clear {
width : 0;
height: 0;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { display: none; }

.clearable {
 background:
 url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhBwAHAIAAAP///
 5KSkiH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAHAAcAAAIMTICmsGrIXnLxuDMLADs=);  
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-color: #fff;
 background-position: left -98% center;  
 background-position-x: -98%;
 line-height: 1.7em; 
 width: 70%;
 }

 .clearable.x  { 
         background-position: left 99% center; 
         background-position-x: 99%;
         background-position-y: 40%;
        }
  .clearable.onX{ cursor: pointer; }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function tog(v) { return v ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass'; }

        $(document).on('input', '.clearable', function () {
            $(this)[tog(this.value)]('x');
        }).on('mousemove', '.x', function (e) {
            $(this)[tog(this.offsetWidth - 30 < e.screenX - this.getBoundingClientRect().left)]('onX');
        }).on('click', '.onX', function () {
            $(this).removeClass('x onX').val('').change();
            autocompleteSearch();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When the iPhone keyboard control is activated you wont be able to invoke your javascript on that element. If the click event was bound to a different element then it would work.

You could for instance wrap a div around your code and style it to look like an input box.

```
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <a href="" onclick="clearFunction();">X</a>
</div>
```